# How to solve Laravel with sail "start-container": executable file not found

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

Im trying to deploy my laravel app using docker with laravel sail. Then I created docker-compose.yml file and Dockerfile like below.

docker-compose.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${HMR_PORT:-8080}:8080'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '${DB_HOST}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

But, when I try to run docker-compose up, I get this below error. I have been trying this for now 2 days. I installed sail properly.

```
ERROR: for 7fd8f64d5ed1_proj_laravel.test_1  Cannot start service laravel.test: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "start-container": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for laravel.test  Cannot start service laravel.test: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "start-container": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Here is my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=here_goes_db_name
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=tyutyu
```

How can I fix this ??

Answer (score 1):

The default docker container [should copy a bash script called `start-container` from your project root to the container during build](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1da083e30e6b0d646535c0afc2afeffdccb7181d/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile#L56). If you for example removed it from your project root, it can not copy it and run it later. So the steps to fix it are:

1. Restore the `start-container` script to your project root, you can find it [here](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/start-container)
2. Rebuild the image with `docker-compose build`

And everything should work again. I suspect step 2 is even optional as [the entire project gets mounted as a volume](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/docker-compose.stub#L22).